# Erro de cache no react-native para versão do IOS

Tags: node.js, ios, react-native, xcode

Estou trabalhando numa aplicação dentro de um diretório novo, porém o emulador insiste em chamar uma outra aplicação de uma pasta que já foi apagada. Onde está o problema?

Estou utilizando o XCode... Segui todo o procedimento para fazer um projeto novo:

**Instalei todas as dependências:**

XCode, Android Studio, node, watchman, jdk8, react-native-cli, react-devtools, expo-cli, cocoapods...

Fiz todo o passo-a-passo:

1. `react-native init meuProjetoNovo`
2. `npm install`
3. `npm install yarn`
4. `react-native start`
5. `cd meuProjetoNovo/ios/`
6. `pod install`
7. `cd ..`
8. `react-native run-ios`

Configurei instalei os pods para o IOS assimilar as rotas na pasta do: meuProjetoNovo/ios

O que não está muito claro na [documentação de como fazer](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps#3-install-cocoapods).

Configurei a estrutura de diretórios, [conforme a documentação](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps#1-set-up-directory-structure).

E mesmo assim é como se a rota estivesse presa a uma aplicação antiga.

**No terminal aparece tudo ok:**

> ArvoreEducacao git:(master) ✗ react-native run-ios
>   info Found Xcode workspace "ArvoreEducacao.xcworkspace"
>   info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace ArvoreEducacao.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme ArvoreEducacao -destination id=7399C5C4-4245-41CD-88B9-564ED1EDB3EE -derivedDataPath build/ArvoreEducacao")
>   ............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
>   info Installing "build/ArvoreEducacao/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ArvoreEducacao.app"
>   info Launching "org.reactjs.native.example.ArvoreEducacao"
>   success Successfully launched the app on the simulator

Ele carrega a tela normal até o fim... e depois aparece uma tela vermelha quebrando tudo chamando uma aplicação nada a ver antiga...

> Editado até aqui - Fiz o que foi sugerido:
>   `npm start --reset-cache ou watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean --force && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache`

O que aconteceu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Log:**

```
> ArvoreEducacao@0.0.1 start /Users/ivanferrer/projects/arvore_educacao/test-react-native/ArvoreEducacao
> react-native start "ou" "watchman" "watch-del-all"
3 info using node@v8.11.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle ArvoreEducacao@0.0.1~prestart: ArvoreEducacao@0.0.1
6 info lifecycle ArvoreEducacao@0.0.1~start: ArvoreEducacao@0.0.1
7 verbose lifecycle ArvoreEducacao@0.0.1~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle ArvoreEducacao@0.0.1~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/ivanferrer/projects/arvore_educacao/test-react-native/ArvoreEducacao/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle ArvoreEducacao@0.0.1~start: CWD: /Users/ivanferrer/projects/arvore_educacao/test-react-native/ArvoreEducacao
10 silly lifecycle ArvoreEducacao@0.0.1~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-native start "ou" "watchman" "watch-del-all"' ]
11 silly lifecycle ArvoreEducacao@0.0.1~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle ArvoreEducacao@0.0.1~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: ArvoreEducacao@0.0.1 start: `react-native start "ou" "watchman" "watch-del-all"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid ArvoreEducacao@0.0.1
15 verbose cwd /Users/ivanferrer/projects/arvore_educacao/test-react-native/ArvoreEducacao
16 verbose Darwin 18.5.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start" "--reset-cache" "ou" "watchman" "watch-del-all"
18 verbose node v8.11.4
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error ArvoreEducacao@0.0.1 start: `react-native start "ou" "watchman" "watch-del-all"`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the ArvoreEducacao@0.0.1 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Continua assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você poderia tentar fazer um `npm start --reset-cache` ou `watchman watch-del-all && 
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* &&
rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && 
rm -rf node_modules/ 
&& npm cache clean --force &&
npm install && 
npm start -- --reset-cache`. Se estiver utilizando um simulador tente limpar seu cache também, indo em seu XCode menu clique em: **Projeto -> Limpar e construir pasta**

Comment: aqui é inglês: Product > Clear Build Folder ?

Comment: Isso mesmo, pensei que estava em português e traduzi do original :p

Comment: Sobre os novos erros que apareceram, de uma olhada [nesse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle) tópico do Stack em Inglês